# Customized Exception Class should extend Exception or Throwable?

Tags: java, exception

public class CustomizedException extends Exception{}

OR

public class CustomizedException extends Throwable{}

Comment: It depends - what are you doing with the exception class and what behaviour should it have

Comment: The Throwable api doc has the answer: *Instances of two subclasses, Error and Exception, are conventionally used to indicate that exceptional situations have occurred.* It also shows that it has no other subclass than Error and Exception.

Comment: @Mark: I am wrapping the exceptions into my own exception such that it becomes easier for users accessing my Rest API to handle it their way.

Comment: @Mark No, it doesn't. Custom exceptions should *never* extend `Throwable` directly.

Comment: @chrylis Yes that makes sense - Custom exceptions  should extend Exception - I misread as classes should extend on or the other which does depend one use - but I bet it should be Exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only two kinds of `Throwable`, exceptions and errors. You should never extend or throw an `Error` unless writing internal JVM code such as an agent or class loader. Always use an exception, and it often makes sense to extend (and thus make more specific) an existing exception class such as `IllegalArgumentException` or `IllegalStateException`.

Comment: Why sholud extending or throwing an Error a bad practic? To what I understand, incase you extend Throwable, you are in more control of exception handling, i.e. handling both Exception and Error.

Comment: A `Throwable` is *not* necessarily an `Exception`, and it makes *handling* more difficult, since calling code may be able to handle an `Exception` but can't handle an `Error` (and official guides discourage catching `Throwable`, since `Error` is specifically for unrecoverable problems).